# Jenkins Error fetching remote repo 'origin'

Tags: .net, git, jenkins

I have recently tried to integrate jenkins i am facing pulling the code itself from git into jenkins workspace. Please if someone can help me following is error message I am getting:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\sample Test App\workspace
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/sample/windows-sample-client.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/sample/windows-sample-client.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe config --local credential.username balraj-sample # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe config --local credential.helper store --file=\"C:\Windows\TEMP\git6022918740990470673.credentials\" # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/sample/windows-sample-client.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://github.com/sample/windows-sample-client.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:810)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1066)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1097)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1269)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:607)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/sample/windows-sample-client.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code -1:
stdout: 
stderr: 
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1719)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1463)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:314)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:808)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: null
Finished: FAILURE
```

After adding SSH RSA key for local git to access my repository I am getting following error in jenkin:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\sample Test App\workspace
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe config remote.origin.url git@github.com:sample/windows-sample-client.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:sample/windows-sample-client.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:sample/windows-sample-client.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@github.com:sample/windows-sample-client.git
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:810)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1066)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1097)
        at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1269)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:607)
        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:sample/windows-sample-client.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1719)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1463)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:63)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:314)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:808)
        ... 11 more
ERROR: null
Finished: FAILURE
```

I reinstalled git and added ssh private key to jenkins also as global credential. After that I am getting following error:

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Gitsample\workspace
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe config remote.origin.url git@github.com:sample/windows-sample-client.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:sample/windows-sample-client.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:sample/windows-sample-client.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@github.com:sample/windows-sample-client.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:810)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1066)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1097)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1269)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:607)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:sample/windows-sample-client.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1719)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1463)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:314)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:808)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: null
```

Comment: With `core.askpass=true`, it might be that Git is prompting you on the command line in Jenkins, but not getting any input, which leads to the timeout. Is this a custom script you're running?

Comment: @tony19 I am just following the steps mentioned here: http://www.frictionlesscode.com/have-continuous-integration-with-jenkins-in-30-mins/

Comment: I am running this via jenkins console and git plugin. Not through custom script.

Comment: Currently my git repository is a private one. Can this also happen because of that?

Comment: I don't think the fact that it's private is causing a problem. It seems to be related to missing credentials, which lead to a prompt. Your log shows that the repo contains `.gitcredentials`, which is not part of the tutorial. I think you'd have to solve that problem to get around this hangup. Either make the project public (e.g., on GitHub) or remove the password (assuming a throw-away test repo).

Comment: I have tried to set the credentials as much as possible from the jenkins interface but no success. Is there some tutorial which i can follow?

Comment: you are running Jenkins in windows machine this is a conflict with your Git version and Visual studio 2015 default git by microsoft

Comment: Changing your question after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've received. It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered. If you now have a new or additional question, create a new post and ask it there; you can link back to this one if needed for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is due to incompatible version of git that maybe have been installed with one of Microsoft products such as Visual Studio, what you can do:

Try to uninstall **GIT** and **[Git Credential Manager for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows)**, then Install GCM again which will install the propriate virsion of git, then you will not have this problem.

Comment: Still causing the same issue. I have unistalled git v2.8 and when i installed from gcm it installed 2.7 but jenkins still throws the same issue.

Comment: Now the error changed to permission denied. I have updated the question

Comment: so yes I answered the original question : )

Comment: configure your git-config and add your SSH key to github or whatever server your are working with to get ride of this err

Comment: I did added the public key to github and when i am trying to access from command prompt it is giving following success message: Hi balraj-sample! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.  But always causing the issue from jenkin

Comment: @ZeRubeus, You assume the problem has to do with Visual Studio and GCM, but the OP makes no mention of either.

Comment: look at the tags .net jenkins and git so , and I've faced the exact same issue